# Symfony entity type - how to get the chosen value

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity, symfony-forms

```
...        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($foo)
        ->add('deviceId', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'FooBundle:Foo',
            'choice_label' => 'deviceId'
        ))
...
```

How can I find out which option for deviceId was selected by the user.

```
...
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
/*Getting the value that was selected
and doing something with it
for exampe removing it from the database*/
}
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that before verify if form have been submited and if it is valid you have do this :

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

In this case you can access it directly because your object have been updated

```
$yourObject->getDeviceId()
```

You can also access to form data like this :

```
$form->getData();
```

Comment: `$form['deviceId']->getData();` is what i was looking for, thanks for the help @DOZ .